# Cannot set the ContentType of a blob in Azure Data Lake Gen2 in csharp

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I'm using the [Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake) nuget package to write and append file on my Azure Storage account that is enabled for Data Lake Gen2 (including hierarchy).

However, I need to set the Content Type of a new file I create and I don't succeed in it, although I thought I had things written correctly.  Here's my code:

```cs
public async Task<bool> WriteBytes(string fileName, byte[] recordContent, string contentType)
{
    var directory = await CreateDirectoryIfNotExists();
    var fileClient = await directory.CreateFileAsync(fileName, 
        new PathHttpHeaders 
        {
            ContentType = contentType
        })).Value;

    long recordSize = recordContent.Length;
    var recordStream = new MemoryStream(recordContent);

    await fileClient.AppendAsync(recordStream, offset: 0);
    await fileClient.FlushAsync(position: recordSize);
    return true;
}
```

The result after the execution of the above code looks like this (the default content-type is kept):

[image]

Thanks for any insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the behavior you're seeing. Basically the issue is with `fileClient.FlushAsync()` method. Before calling this method, I checked the content type of the file and it was set properly. However after execution of this method, the content type was changed to `application/octet-stream` (which is the default).

Looking at the documentation for this method [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.datalake.datalakefileclient.flushasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview), you can also set the headers in this method. I tried doing the same and the content type changed to the desired one.

```
        var headers = new PathHttpHeaders()
        {
            ContentType = "text/plain"
        };
        await fileClient.FlushAsync(position: recordSize, httpHeaders: headers);
```

Comment: Hey Gaurav!  Awesome again!  Confirmed that's the behavior